# Image is not working as expected with constraints

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a root `UIView` (for rendering shadow) and it's content is another `UIVIew` that contains a `UIImage` and some labels at the bottom. When I look at a sample poster with my constraints set up in interface builder, it looks more or less how I want it.

In this screenshot, the `DropshadowUI View` holds the content and renders a shadow. The `CardView` holds both the `UIImageView` and the `UILabel`s at the bottom. The `DropshadowUI View` is transparent, the `CardView` has a blue background and is the full height/width of the dropshadow (w/ a little bit of margin) and the `UIImageView` has a green background to help distinguish the views while testing. You can see that the `UIImageView` takes up roughly 80% of the `CardView` layout, which is desired. The rest of the `CardView` is made up of the `UILabel`s.

[image]

When I run the app however, the constraints don't seem to be working the same way as shown in interface builder. The `UIImageView` stretches to take the entire height of the `CardView`. The `UILabel`s are hidden from sight because of this. Judging from the green blur behind my UINavigationBar and UITabBar, it appears that the `UIImageView` is stretching vertically beyond the extents of the visible area, despite the image not even being that large.

[image]

The `UIImageView` image is set in the interface builder for now (will be set programmatically when this is working). The Content Mode is Aspect Fit. Why does the `UIImageView` stretch vertically? The `Status` label has a Bottom Space to bottom of Superview set at 8 points. The `Year` label's Bottom Space is constrained to the top of Status. The `Movie Title`s bottom is constrained to the top of `Year`. `Movie Title` has it's top constrained to the bottom of the `UIImageView`. The assumption was that the labels would prevent the image view from growing on the bottom, and instead getting taller by stretching the top (which is constrained to the superview views top.

Is there something wrong with my constraints? I'm still learning the auto-layout system, so if there's something in the screenshots that don't help explain my constraints, let me know what I could do to help clarify them.

### Edit

I reset the `UIImageView` to the suggested constraints and ended up with this at runtime, despite the design-time view looking correct.

[image]

Is there a way for me to constrain the UIImageView so that the image can only grow taller, until it runs out of space to fit the rest of the content? I'm missing my bottom label here because now the image is fitting into the `UIImageView` but pushing everything else to far down. I'd rather it try to fill as much horizontal space as it can, until the siblings beneath it can no longer be pushed further down.

*What I get, vs what i want*

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

Select your image and go to **Layout Issues tool > Reset to Suggested Constraints**

Comment: Thanks, please see the edit to my original post explaining the issue after I performed this. I'm not sure why autolayout didn't handle pushing my labels down further like they are shown in IB.

Comment: that got me closer, it's still pushing content down to far though. I've updated my original post again to show the differences.